# Repush entire site from c9.io to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, c9.io

My c9.io site works very well but my heroku site gives "We're sorry, but something went wrong." after a few clicks. Is there a way to push my entire site to heroku instead of just changes? I'm hoping maybe that will fix it on the heroku side.
Thanks, Jon

Comment: `git remote -v` then `git remote rm heroku`. after deleting heroku. Just add it again:  `heroku create`

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in the terminal.

```
git remote -v
git remote rm destination
```

after removing Heroku, add it again.

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
```